# Correct way of catching R2dbcRepository exeptions and throwing another

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc

I'm using `R2dbcRepository` for interacting with database:

```
@Repository
public interface OfficeRepository extends R2dbcRepository<OfficeEntity,Long> {
}
```

and what i want to do is: Fetch office by `FindById` method and if no record exists with this `Id`, want to catch the exeption thrown by `FindById` method (`IllegalStateException`) and throw antother bussines exeption like `RequestedNotFoundException`.

OK?

so i wrote these codes and none of them work:

```
  officeRepository.findById(officeId).handle(
            (officeEntity, synchronousSink) -> {
                if (officeEntity == null)
                    synchronousSink.error(new RequestedNotFoundException("office not found"));
            }
    );
```

---

```
officeRepository.findById(officeId)
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.error(new RequestedNotFoundException("Office not found"));
```

and

```
 Mono.just(officeId)
                    .map(officeRepository::findById)
                            .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.error(new RequestedNotFoundException("Office not found")));
```

So how can i write this code??

by the way, i don't want to use traditional `try{} catch{}` to solve this problem, i think there must be a cleaner way.

Thanks

Comment: YOur starting point is already wrong. It won't throw an exception., it will just return an empty mono.

Comment: @M.Deinum not it's throw IllegalStateException and i catched with try catch.

Comment: It will throw an `IllegalStateException` if the passed in ID is `null` not if the record isn't found. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/reactive/ReactiveCrudRepository.html#findById(ID)

Comment: @M.Deinum the base class is `R2bcCRepository` not `ReactiveCrudRepository`

Comment: [R2DbcRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/repository/R2dbcRepository.html) is a `ReactiveCrudRepository` and thus it inherits its `findById` method with the same charateristics.

Comment: kidding me man? i'm telling you the id is not null. do you want i give you anydesk access to see it?? :/ are you ok to start a video call in google meet?

Comment: No I'm not. Unless you are willing to pay my hourly consultancy fee. The documentation clearly states that it works in that way and it makes no sense to throw an exception in a reactive stack. The Spring Data provided implementation doesn't throw an exception if nothing is found it returns an empty mono (as it should). So unless you replaced the default spring data implementation of the repository it doesn't throw an exception and you are looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: The implementation shows that it works like that as well, so you either replaced the default implementation in the repository or there is something else going on. What is the cause (the message and stacktrace) of the `IllegalStateException` you get. And if it is an exception here, there is nothing else to do then a try/catch in the service method.